# I have tried unsuccessfully to upgrade from 23.04 to 23.10

Tags: apt, upgrade, repository, 23.04

I get 3 messages:

```
E: the repository'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic Release' does not have a Release file
updating from such a repository can't be done securely and is therefore disabled by default
W: see apt-secure (8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details
```

Do I create the required repository on my computer?  If I create the required repository on my computer what are the configuration details?

Comment: Edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` and remove the line with `kinetic` as that refers to an older Ubuntu version than what you have installed … Then run `sudo apt update` again.

Comment: You mention an upgrade from *lunar* (or 23.04) to *mantic* (23.10), then why does your pasted details refer to *kinetic* or 22.10?  Ubuntu 22.10 (*kinetic*) reached EOL long ago - https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/07/27/ubuntu-22-10-kinetic-kudu-end-of-life-reached-on-july-20-2023/  Please check your question, as your pasted details do **not** match your stated upgrade; showing issues from a *kinetic* or 22.10 system; are you trying to upgrade 22.10 to 23.04?

Answer (score 0):

Check that you are really using Ubuntu 23.04, codenamed "Lunar Lobster". I say this because you mention "Kinetic", but that is the codename of [Ubuntu 22.10](https://canonical.com/blog/canonical-releases-ubuntu-22-10-kinetic-kudu) from last year.

If you are still using 22.10 you must upgrade to 23.04 *first* and only then to 23.10.

If you are not running Kinetic, then:

1. Make a backup copy of `/etc/apt/sources.list`
2. In your preferred editor, change all mentions of `kinetic` to `lunar`.
3. Do the same for all files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`
4. Reboot, just as a precaution.
5. Do a normal full update.
6. Reboot.
7. Then try the upgrade again.